# Export to excel with React and SheetJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, spreadsheet, export-to-excel, sheetjs

I am trying to implement export to excel with React and SheetJs library. Looks like I can download it, but the actual output does not look as expected. 
I receive array of object and use `XLSX.utils.json_to_sheet([data])` API to converts an array of JS objects to a worksheet. Problem is :
[image]

I've reproduced it [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-rihmaj?file=index.js)

Answer (score 6):

Fixed here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-yg6pt5?file=exportToExcel.js

Bug was with  `XLSX.utils.json_to_sheet([data])` `XLSX.utils.json_to_sheet(data)` this utils use object of array as aurgument instead array of objects

Change `wb.SheetNames.push(''); wb.Sheets[''] = ws` to  `wb.SheetNames.push('sheet1'); wb.Sheets['sheet1'] = ws`
so that you will not get data recovery error while opening file